# Spring web mvc Collection in entity class

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa, collections

Lets say i have 2 entities, Dish and Ingrediënt.

As we all know a Dish consists out of multiple Ingredients, so let's say:

Dish.java:

```
@Entity
public class Dish {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    protected long id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "dish", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Collection<Ingredient> ingredients;
    //getters & setters
}
```

Ingrediënt.java :

```
    @Entity
    public class Ingredient {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        protected long id;
        private String name;
        //getters &setters
    }
```

If we then have a DishController.java :

```
@Controller
public class DishController {

    Service service;
    public DishController() throws ServiceException {
        service = new ShoppingFacade("JPA");
    }
    @RequestMapping("/showDishOverview")
    protected ModelAndView getDishes() throws ServiceException {
        Collection<Dish> dishes = service.getAllDishes();
        return new ModelAndView("dish/dishOverview", "dishes", dishes);
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/showDishForm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
protected ModelAndView showDishForm(@RequestParam(value = "id") long dishId)throws ServiceException{
        Dish dish = shoppingFacade.getDishById(dishId);
        return new ModelAndView("dish/dishForm", "dish", dish);
}
    @RequestMapping(value = "/editDish", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    protected String updateDish(@ModelAttribute("dish") Dish newDish) throws ServiceException{
        service.updateDish(newDish);
        return "forward:/showDishOverview.htm";
    }
}
```

Now lets say that we select one dish by its id:

```
<a href="showDishForm.htm?id=${dish.getId()}">${dish.getName()}</a>
```

Now the showDishForm method in our controller will be called.
which will send us to dishForm.jsp:

```
<form method="post" action="editDish.htm">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Name </label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="${dish.getName()}" value="${dish.getName()}"/></td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>People</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="people" placeholder="${dish.getPeople()}" value="${dish.getPeople()}"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="hidden" name="ingredients" value="${dish.getIngredient()}" />
                <button type="submit" name="id" value="${dish.getId()}">Save</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>  
</form>
```

How will Spring MVC pass the info from my view to the controller?
Cause I get it working as long as I don't pass any Collections.(comment out `<input type="hidden" name="ingredients" value="${dish.getIngredient()}" />`
)
If i try to pass a Collection i get the message :

> HTTP STATUS 400 -  The request sent by the client was syntactically
>   incorrect

Comment: Can you put in your whole code for form submittion without collection and with collection to assist in identifying the issue?

Comment: done... hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring uses Converters, for all standard classes these are already implemented.
For custon classes like this List, you have to write your own converter.